# How do I add custom highlight to the dropdown spinner textbox to replace the blue tint?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using a dropdown spinner in my apps.I am trying to replace the blue tint at the primary selected cell with a custom color.Any hint how to go about the same? Here's the code I have for the dropdown spinner:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        foo:customFont="Roboto-Regular.ttf"
        android:paddingLeft="18dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/manage_market_category_btnbg"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="16sp" 
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

which is called for the spinner cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code : http://android-holo-colors.com/ for the spinner :)

Comment: so I just select the spinner and add this to my application and it will work ?

Comment: yeah, select the required colors, then select spinner and then download the zip file and then add it to your classes and you should be good